# Vue - show loader while computed property being computed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, computed-properties

**EDIT - Found that sorting is quick, real issue is performance of rendering huge list, so already answered**

pls explain to me, why this does nothing:

I have array of thousands of items, there is a button for sorting them by some prop (changes "sortBy" prop. Sorting items takes **almost 2 seconds**, at least that how long after the click does the list change. During computing (until new list displayed) i want to display some "Loading" element. Im not aware, byt maybe Vue has some app-wide state to tell something is being recomputed?

```
<div v-if="loading">Wait pliz</div>
<div @click="sortBy='ctg'">SortByCtg</div>
<div v-for="item in sortedRows">{{item.ctg}} , {{item.name}} .... </div>
```

and the computed prop fn:

```
data: function(){ 
   return { 
    'sortby': 'name', 
    'sortbyDir': 1, 
    'loading': false,
    'rows': [ {'name':'abc','ctg':'def'}, ...] 
  }
},
computed: {
    sortedRows: function(){
     this.loading = true; //  <<< should show element
     var sortby = this.sortby;
     var sortbyDir = this.sortbyDir;
     var sorted = this.rows;
     sorted = this.rows.sort(function(a, b) { 
      return sortbyDir * a[sortby].localeCompare(b[sortby]); 
     });
    this.loading = false; //  <<< hide element
    return sorted;
  }
},
...
```

but the **"loading" element never shows**. May it be sort is quick, and what is taking the time is the nodes generation itself? Then can i anyhow show the loader? Maybe somehow use next tick? I tried but with no result.

Comment: In the code you show us, you didn't show when `sordedRows` is call and if `this.loading` is a reactive property and what is the starting value. To test your guess about the fact the sort is so quick that it just happen, you can simply comment the `this.loading = false`, and check if the div shows up.

Comment: @MarioSantini ok, i thought thats clear, but added it as u pointed out

Comment: @PM_KLS Do you have this variable `loading` initialized in your `data: function() {}` ? I see only 'sortBy' and 'rows' as declared ones.

Comment: @Vitomir sure  'loading' initialized as false, added to sample code

Comment: UPDATE - measured using difference Date.now(); and at start and end of fn , seems to be only about 15ms... so the real slowdown may be elsewhere - probaly at readrawing the list itself bc of too many elements.... any ideas?

Comment: You can test your code by adding a timeout to this.loading = false. If the icon does not show up, you know for sure that it isn't showing.

Comment: @Wimanicesir it is showing, i just found the sort fn is quick, what tkaes that long time is generating the nodes in document (about 3500 table rows at the moment). Som im now looking at the posiibility of checking if the app is active in redrawing... ideas ?

Comment: There are a lot of options here. I would advise you to make a paginated table to prevent loading too much. I don't know what your goal is with the data, but you could always consider using Object.Freeze(). This removes the reactivity but should generate much quicker :)

Comment: The first rule for showing so many records in a table is to use pagination, no matter if it will with page selection (1, 2, 3, etc. ) or it will load like 20-30 records while scrolling. In my projects, I always use pagination with pages and the max records per page is 100.

However, this means that you will have to modify the backend, too, if you are getting the data from an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is quick (few miliseconds),
what really takes time is rendering the long list

Comment: This should be a comment. Also OP pointed this out in his comment 18 minutes before you posted this anwser.

Comment: @Wimanicesir well im the OP and i chose to answer my own question, because i see this is not the sorting issue, its rendering performacne issue, so i consider this solved

Comment: @Wimanicesir, you're completely wrong. Just because it's brief it doesn't mean it's not the answer to the question. Or the correct answer. Could it be improved and/or expanded? Absolutely! Should it be a comment? Absolutely not. It is detrimental for [SO] to post answers as comments. They tend not to help future users having the same problem and it hinders proper indexing and they also determine users who would otherwise answer the question from posting the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @tao I missed this was the OP. However, I can only change my vote if this is editted. Also this isn't an answer, this is saying what the problem was, still not how to solve it. I don't know how future users are going to use this 'answer'.. IMO, this still should be editted in the question as the real solution will derive from this.

Answer (score -1):

"Sorting items takes almost 2 seconds" and "May it be sort is quick" are against each other, but you can't see the loading indicator in either of them. Usually, a sort finishes in some ms, you can barely see anything. Another possibility is if it runs for 2 seconds (slow algorithm or rendering thousands of rows on the page after sort), it blocks the main thread and you won't see any changes on the page.

Your code should work, but you shouldn't change data in computed. The sort method mutating the original array, and you change the loading variable. It can also run multiple times unnecessarily.

Comment: yeas i already found sort is really only ~20ms, so the long time is when the items beeing rerendered. About i should not change data in cpmputed, thats the whole point of computed... i use console log, and see recomputing ONLY happens if i click button, so it really does it 'once' upon click... but how can i wait for large list to be rerendered? can i tell re-rendering has ended ?

Comment: This should have been a comment. Then you would also see that half of your answer is already said :)

Comment: Computed is a getter, it should only alter a copy of the data. From the doc: "It is important to remember that computed getter functions should only perform pure computation and be free of side effects.". To speed up rendering, you can use any of these techniques: infinity scroll, pagination, virtual list